# Read the source of a script tag from the cache in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I'm adding some error reporting to my application. I want to be able to report the method name from a class, even thought the function may be anonymous.

So far my solution involves reading the source of the script tag by loading it with XmlHttpRequest. My problem is that Firefox will not load from cache and always calls out to the server (chrome uses the cache and I haven't started in IE yet). Since my project has thousands of lines of code, making a second request to the server takes unwanted time.

Is anyone aware of a way to make Firefox check the cache? Barring that, is there a way to read the script source directly from the script tag? Is there some other way to get the source that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Have you considered filing a bug against Firefox? http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ (If it asks you where you want to file the bug, use Product: "Core", Component: "Networking: Cache".) The security rules are different for `<script>` vs. XHR... but that's really no reason for Firefox to skip the cache.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. Could be a bug.

Comment: @Jason You should add this as an answer so I can give you the check mark. While I doubt I'll be able to point to any specifications that apply (and therefore make a good case that this is a bug) I do agree that this is a problem with Firefox.

Comment: Heh! Done. If you file a bug report, please post a link to it here so that later readers can find out what happened.

Comment: @hemlock, FF caches ajax requests just fine. You need to send suitable http headers to convince FF that the request is capable of being, and worthy of being cached.

Comment: @chris I think you need to re-read the question. I'm not trying to cache the request. I'm trying to get the response to come from the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered filing a bug against Firefox? Use [bugzilla.mozilla.org](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org). (If it asks you where you want to file the bug, use Product: "Core", Component: "Networking: Cache".)

The security rules are different for `<script>` vs. XHR... but that's really no reason for Firefox to skip the cache.

Answer (score 0):

This site could help:
http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/
http://www.httpwatch.com/demos/ajax_caching/

It talked a lot about HTTP header manipulation, so you should write a PHP script that outputs the script content, and add apporarite caching headers.

Also, did you try `jQuery.ajax({type: "script", cache: true})`? It has a cache option.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I visited that site earlier, but I must admit, I didn't look at it hard enough. I'll look into that tomorrow. Just too frustrated today. Thanks.

Comment: I looked over that page. It primarily applies to IE and in the opposite direction: trying to get IE to drop the cache rather than use it.